# AJAX recognizing if the result call is an error or a success

Tags: ajax, request, containers

multiple request to fill different containers?

ajax/javascript example:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(#submit).click(function()
{
   $var = $("#result");
   $.post("ajax.php", {request : $var}, function()
   {
     $("#container1").fadeOut(400, function(){ $("#container1").html(result); });
     $("#container1").fadeIn();
   });
});
});
```

ajax.php example:

```
<?php
 if($_POST['request']==1) // or several complicated conditions
 { ?><div>This is a success</div> 

   //if success I would like to load another piece of html inside an id="container2".
 <?php }

 if($_POST['request']==0)
 { ?><div>This is a disaster</div> <?php }
?>
```

That's the question if the response is 1 (or This is a success) I would like to load another piece of html code inside a container (container2) with a different id from the original container id used for the request within the post method(in this case "container1").
Is there a way to do it?

Thanks for your thoughts and answers!

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $(#submit).click(function()
    {
       $var = $("#result");
       $.post("ajax.php", {request : $var}, function(a,b)
       {
    if(b=="error"){
    Do Somthing...
    } else{
         $("#container1").fadeOut(400, function(){ $("#container1").html(result); });
         $("#container1").fadeIn();
}
       });
    });
    });
```

Comment: I don't really undertand it. I don't understand how the container2 gets filled in case all the condition to a success are met. Because the success of container1 fires the request for container2 to get filled.

Comment: don't you mean that if ajax post was successful? well then second argument returns the status of ajax command whether it was successful or not

Comment: No, in my example if the user select an option let's say "1" the ajax post will be successful and if the user select "0" the ajax call will be also successful. My example means that if the user select "0" (in the php) it will be considered as an error (but I am not refering to the ajax post) and in the case the user selects 1 I would like to fire a php content to be filled in <div id="container2"> I don't know how to do it since in my example I used "#container1" but I need to keep it like this... to post other things.